# Why is Azure deployment slower on Windows 2012 Server than on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: asp.net, .net, performance, azure, windows-server-2012

I have an ASP.NET (Webforms) working with .Net Framework 4.0.

If I deploy that site with `osFamily="1"` (on a Windows 2008 server) the `.NET CLR` takes `120 ms` average (according to NewRelic logs).

If I take the exact site and I deploy it with `osFamily="3"` (on  a Windows 2012 server) the `.NET CLR` takes more than `500 ms`.

I know I should move to `MVC4` and perhaps `.Net Framework 4.5`, but I would like to know if anyone else has had the same problem and if you know what could be causing this?

[image]

**Edit**

Looks like `osFamily=2` also has the same problem.

Comment: Em... What exactly takes longer?

Comment: Im gonna run a profiler to see exactly what's going on. I think could be something related to azure sdk 2.0 and 1.7 (I am using 1.7). This comes from another issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813664/programmatically-configure-azure-cache-client

Comment: not yet :) still playing arround. I had a recent experience with another deployment. I think it's related to the use of classic aspx pages. Should not happen with a proper MVC, but I still didn't had the chance to prove it

Comment: This link may help you : http://netmf.codeplex.com/workitem/2004

Comment: @Portekoi your link is related to the Micro Framework, I don't think any of it will apply here.

Comment: What is your application pool type? Classic or Pipeline?

Comment: Pipeline, framework 4.0

Comment: I wonder have you ever tested this kind of stuff on local machine with different versions of Windows before putting the Azure tag. People often encounter different issues when they deploy to Azure, but the issues are not Azure related at all. I don't question the fact that there is an issue!Apparently there is, but the question is more related, IMO, to different versions of Windows Server, rather than having anything to do with Azure specifically! And will probably get more adequate answers on ServerFault of SuperUser.

Comment: I am using Azure since 2010. Deploying to a physical server is kind of an anachronism for me :)

Comment: Have you tried opening a support ticket with MS?

Answer (score 2):

From the [forum discussion](https://www.ghielectronics.com/community/forum/topic?id=11836&page=3) it seems that it's a known issue.

The issue is reported [here](https://netmf.codeplex.com/workitem/2004).

> Upgrading from VS2010 to VS2012, we noticed that deploying is very slow, which can be worked around but then stepping in code is very slow as well.
>
> First, we thought it maybe the device but it is very slow even in the emulator. This machine we tested, is i7 processor with 12MB of RAM. This also seem the case for many who have reported on our forums.
>
> [Read more](https://netmf.codeplex.com/workitem/2004).

A solution seems to be the changing the driver to winusb (`C:\Program Files\GHI Electronics\GHI Premium NETMF v4.2 SDK\USB Drivers\GHI_NETMF_WinUsb`) - according to one of the comments.

Comment: What does .NET micro framework has to do with the OPs question?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the OP's question. He is talking about deployment differences between Windows 2012 and 2008 on Azure. Your link is about Visual Studio 2012 and 2010. Windows != Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-us/7cf664b0-5876-4d6a-b54d-fda46c544c6f/azure-deployment-slower-with-w2012-server-than-w2008-server-or-w2008-server-r2?forum=windowsazuretroubleshooting:

***'I tried with .NET 4.5 with the same results. I think is something related to Azure SDK 1.7 & 2.0***

***[Programmatically configure Azure cache client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813664/programmatically-configure-azure-cache-client)' Answer by Jordi Torra***

It seems to be a problem with the Azure SDK 1.7 & 2.0.

Comment: Did you check that the post you posted above is the same as the OP of this thread?

Comment: @JuneT It's still a valid answer

Comment: Did you check that the MSDN answer was marked as answered not by the OP? And that as per OP of the post above, this is not yet answered?

Comment: @JuneT It was still marked as an answer, and it ***is*** a valid answer: 'Marked as answer by Qin Dian Tang - MSFTMicrosoft community contributor, Moderator Thursday, June 13, 2013 2:16 AM'